# How does the Camel Jetty component work in Akka?

Tags: apache-camel, akka-camel

In the following example (taken from [Akka Camel doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/camel.html#Consumer)), the Jetty HTTP component is used to receive HTTP messages. Does it mean that the actor start a new Jetty server?

```
import akka.camel.{ CamelMessage, Consumer }

class MyEndpoint extends Consumer {
  def endpointUri = "jetty:http://localhost:8877/example"

  def receive = {
    case msg: CamelMessage => { /* ... */ }
    case _                 => { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct, `jetty` consumer will start an embedded Jetty server and bind it to the specified port.

Here's a quote from [the official documentation](https://camel.apache.org/jetty.html):

> The jetty component provides HTTP-based endpoints for consuming and producing HTTP requests. **That is, the Jetty component behaves as a simple Web server.**

Comment: Thanks. What happens if I have multiple Jetty end points? Will it start multiple Jetty servers? Trying to evaluate using Camel Jetty HTTP vs Akka-html

Comment: It should start only a single server, take a look at this link: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Using-a-single-port-for-all-Jetty-Consumers-td5736267.html

Comment: Or, better yet, [code for Jetty component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/e4b2c99591f54f4d909e1e245b0c8d012c89a8c2/components/camel-jetty-common/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/jetty/JettyHttpComponent.java#L316), where you can see that the server is only started for different protocol, hostname and port combinations.